# Infinite end-less horizontal smooth scroll news ticker without marquee tag

Tags: php, infinite-scroll, horizontal-scrolling, marquee, news-ticker

`In jQuery PHP, I need an infinite horizontal ticker with an end-less loop of data taken from external JSON via Ajax. I tired it with marquee with PHP loop without ajax, it's working but not infinite looping. Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
  <div class="__ticker">
        <marquee scrollamount="11">
        <?php
            foreach( $json as  $splitRec ) {
                $NumRec++;
                echo "<p>".$splitRec['text']."</p>";
                if($NumRec == 15) break;
            }
        ?>
        </marquee>
    </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the documentation goes, the marquee element is only suitable for text it seems. You have an  in it.

Comment: This marquee element does not provide infinite scrolling